# Programmatically changing the title of a dygraph chart

Tags: dygraphs

I'm having trouble programmatically changing the title of a dygraph chart when the user clicks on the chart.  I'm able to get the value they clicked, but I can't seem to change the title property.  Here's what I'm trying:

```
clickCallback: function (e, p, points) {
    for (var i = 0; i < dygraphs.length; i++) {
        var g = dygraphs[i];

        var pos = Dygraph.findPos(g.graphDiv);
        var canvasx = Dygraph.pageX(e) - pos.x;
        var canvasy = Dygraph.pageY(e) - pos.y;
        var xy = g.toDataCoords(canvasx, canvasy);
        var x = xy[0];
        var rows = g.numRows();
        var closestRow = -1;
        var smallestDiff = -1;

        for (var row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
            var date = g.getValue(row, 0); // millis
            var diff = Math.abs(date - x);
            if (smallestDiff < 0 || diff < smallestDiff) {
                smallestDiff = diff;
                closestRow = row;
            }
        }

        if (closestRow != -1) {
            //Update the marker label
            var text = g.rawData_[closestRow][1];

            g.updateOptions({
                title: text
            }, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a link to my "broken" version.  Not sure if it matters, but I'm using 1.1.1:
http://jsfiddle.net/ye97owtm/2/

Comment: Just to be clear, after I set the new "title" property, the title doesn't change on the graph.  Interestingly, if I debug, I can see that the g.user_attrs_.title property is updated, but the title at the top of the graph doesn't change.

Comment: I'm unable to [reproduce this](http://jsfiddle.net/eM2Mg/6341/). Can you post a broken demo using dygraphs.com/fiddle?

Comment: Added jsfiddle link.

Comment: @danvk The only difference I can see is that I'm changing the title inside the clickCallback function.

Comment: Wow... I removed the ", true" parameter from the updateOptions function and it's working.  My apologies for wasting your time.  I thought the second parameter being true would trigger a redraw.

Comment: Yep, that's the ["block redraw" parameter](http://dygraphs.com/jsdoc/symbols/Dygraph.html#updateOptions).